# Get actual height of document with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a problem with my jQuery plugin, I want to display footer in specific way right before end of page. For this I get actual bottom position and compare it with height of entire body.

But there is a problem jQuery function height() return bad value. For example I know that site has height of 5515px but function returns to me a value: 8142px

I use the plugin mCustomScrollbar in few places on page, and I think that it may cause the problem. I can't disable it, because page has elements which require it to look good.

My code:

```
(function($){
    $.fn.scrollingElements = function(){
        var height = $(window).height();
        var max_height = $(document).height();
        var prev_top = $(window).scrollTop();
        var prev_bottom = top + height;
        $(window).scroll(function(){
            var top = $(window).scrollTop();
            var bottom = top + height;

            console.log(max_height, bottom);

            if(prev_top < height && top > height){
                // console.log('show header', 'show sticky', 'show footer small');
            }
            if(prev_top > height && top < height){
                // console.log('hide header', 'hide sticky', 'hide footer');
            }
            if(prev_top < 2*height && top > 2*height){
                // console.log('show sroll top');
            }
            if(prev_top > 2*height && top < 2*height){
                // console.log('hide scroll top');
            }

            if(prev_bottom < max_height - 100 && bottom > max_height - 100){
                // console.log('show footer large');
            }
            if(prev_bottom > max_height - 100 && bottom < max_height - 100){
                // console.log('show footer small');
            }

            prev_top = top;
            prev_bottom = bottom;

        });
        $(window).resize(function(){
            height = $(window).height();
        });
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Answering to Tommy Riordan: 
changing $(document).height() to document.body.clientHeight didn't work still  getting bad results. Tried using $('body').height() with same effect.

Comment: Why not just use `position: fixed; bottom: 0` in CSS to do this?

Comment: minus the resulted height manually...

Comment: Rory, no i can't., Bhojendra what do you mean? The page has dynamic height I cant put it there manually.

Comment: please try to get body height it may be work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Please use

> document

instead of **window** 
for example :

> $(window).resize(function(){
>               height = $(document).height();
>           });